# How to verify that a function X() is getting called from function Y() not from function Z()?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, lynxos

Could you Please provide me any example How to verify that a function X() is getting called from function Y() not from function Z()?

Using 'C' or assembly language?

Thanks in advance.

***Update:02-03-2015***

1. Suppose kernel source code there are so many drivers calling the same function, like driver source code of SPI (Serial Phepheral Interface) and GPIO (General Purpose Input Output) is calling same function say "bzero()".

   > void bzero(void *s, size_t n);
2. I am going to test SPI and GPIO driver (driver code can not be modified). For that I have written the test driver. I can only call the function exposed from my test driver.

   uint8_t SPI_read_write(uint8_t byte_out, char *s) // Function 1
   {
       bzero(s,sizeof(struct_global1));
       return byte_in;
   }

   uint8_t GPIO_read_write(uint8_t byte_out, char *s)// Function 2
   {
       bzero(s,sizeof(struct_global2));
       return byte_in;
   }

   int main()// Test driver
   {
       SPI_read_write(arg1,arg2);// When I call this function from test driver it will call bzero
   }
3. Both the finction SPI_read_write() and GPIO_read_write() function calls the "bzero" function.
   I need to ensure that "bzero" is getting called at any instance from SPI_read_write() function only.

## **Updates 15-04-2017**

I am not able to get which line is unclear? some function fun1() can be called from N number of other function. how to determine which function called fun1()?

Probably it is related to stack, link register...

Comment: Make it a static function in the same translation unit as `X`. If `Y` is there also, you are out of luck. But frankly, I think this is (literally) an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can check it using a debugger, e.g. the built-in debugger from Code::blocks.

Comment: Check it using `__builtin_return_address`?

Comment: Indeed an XY problem. If the call-chain matters (what about indirect calls?), your code is broken by design.

Comment: You'd have to know what the address of each function is and then walk up down the stack examining the stack frames.

Comment: Byte Magazine once tried to push `came from` as the opposite of `go to`. Only worked on April 1 though.

Comment: Hi David thanks. Can you please tell me how do i know the address of the function and also tell me how to get information about the stack frame?

Comment: It's still not at all clear what you're asking. What do you want to happen differently when `GPIO_read_write` calls `bzero` instead of  `SPI_read_write`? Are `GPIO_read_write`, `SPI_read_write` or `bzero` part of your test driver? Is your example code actually how they been implemented? Does it make a difference if `bzero` isn't called directly by the functions `SPI_read_write` and `GPIO_read_write` but instead are called by other functions that these two `read_write` functions call? Can you change any of these functions? It might help to explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Both the function GPIO_read_write() and SPI_read_write() calls bzero (). But I need to prove that SPI_read_write() called bzero () for a particular instance.

Comment: From my test driver I can call SPI_read_write() function which will call bzero(). The main intention is to ensure that only because of my test driver bzero() was called.  I need the stack frame the function is getting called.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine the name of the function that is calling your function. This is entirely by design, because functions are intended to provide an abstraction that encapsulates a computation or an activity that is independent of the invocation site. Therefore, if you want to know which function is calling your function, the caller needs to provide this information.

C99-compliant compilers provide a way to determine the name of the current function, which can be used to pass to the target function, like this:

```
#define X() x(__func__)

void x(const char* caller) {
    printf("x() is called from %s()\n", caller);
}
void y() {
    X();
}
void z() {
    X();
}
```

The above prints

```
x() is called from y()
x() is called from z()
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/v5Lws2)

Comment: What's GNU-specific about it?  You're using `__func__` which is a pre-defined identifier in C99 and later.  That said, there's nothing to stop a user writing `void Z(void) { X("Y"); }` which fibs about the function that called `Y`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <execinfo.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 void print_function(void *p) {
    char cmd[128];
    FILE *fp;
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "addr2line -e %s -f %p", "print_caller", p);
    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp) {
        char buf[128];
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
           printf("%s", buf);
        }
    }
 }

 void Y() 
{
    print_function(__builtin_return_address(0));
}

void X()
{
    Y();
}

int main()
{
   X();
   return 0;
}

 $ gcc -g -o print_caller print_caller.c
 $ ./print_caller
 X
 /home/viswesn/print_caller.c:24
```

I would also recommend you to view the man page of [BACKTRACE()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace_symbols.3.html) which may provide you more insight on how to view the functions that were called before getting in to the current funciton.

Comment: Thanks. Here you are writing your own function. Calling as you want. So, in that case i can put a debug msg to see which function called which function? correct?

Comment: Actually..In my case I can not modify any function. This is thumb rule. I can call the function X() or function Y() but not allowed to edit.